# Removing one item in a vector containing identical items

Tags: c++, string, vector

Imagine you have a `vector<string> inventory` full of `apple`s and `oranges`. How do you remove a single `apple` rather than all `apple`s in the vector? `std::remove` usually does this because the strings are identical, from what I can tell. Here's the line I think needs to be changed.

```
inventory.erase(remove(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), "apple") inventory.end());
```

Comment: So ... don't use `remove`. Use `find` to find an `apple` and `vector::erase` that.

Answer (score 3):

```
const std::string apple = "apple";
const auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(inventory), std::cend(inventory), apple);

if (it != std::cend(inventory)) inventory.erase(it);
```

You just find the first one and, if it exists, remove.

[**Example**](https://godbolt.org/g/BkSVLf)

Answer (score 2):

As [Edgar Rokyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47801639/4297146) said, you can remove one instance easily using [`std::find()`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and [`std::vector::erase()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/).

```
const auto it = std::find(std::cbegin(inventory), std::cend(inventory), apple);
if (it != std::cend(inventory)) inventory.erase(it);
```

When an item disappears from a vector, and sits somewhere in the middle, then all the items right of it must move one slot to the left, implying an `O(n)` complexity. If you don't care about the order of the elements inside the vector, you can reduce the complexity to `O(1)` by moving the last component to the position of the one you want to remove, and then removing the last position of the vector:

```
auto it = std::find(std::begin(inventory), std::end(inventory), apple);
if (it != std::end(inventory)) {
    *it = std::move(inventory.back());
    inventory.pop_back();
}
```

In this case, a better approach is a generic template function, so you can use it with different types:

```
template<class Container>
inline auto remove_first_coincidence(Container &container, typename Container::value_type const& element) {
    auto it = std::find(std::begin(container), std::end(container), element);
    if (it != std::end(container)) {
        *it = std::move(container.back());
        container.pop_back();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://godbolt.org/g/QtPBMx)

Comment: In `remove_first_coincidence()`, the `container` needs to be passed by reference, not by value, otherwise you are modifying a copy of the container instead of the original.  You need to change that in your demo

Comment: Ups sorry, I copied the code from an old generic implementation in which I used iterators :S little mistake.